# Cosa vuol dire "capitozzo" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Quando franammo tra le foglie grasse, i rovi e la menta del fondo, il Valino alzò appena la testa. Stava troncando con la roncola sul **capitozzo** i rami rossi d’un salice.

Nei dizionari che ho potuto consultare, ho trovato "capitozza" e "capitozzatura", parole che fanno riferimento a un certo modo di potare gli alberi, ma non il termine "capitozzo". Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Il significato di capitozza penso vada bene anche per capitozzo, cioè un ramo principale della pianta tagliato corto.

Comment: @abarisone: Su quale dizionario appare questa definizione?

Comment: veramente l’ho trovato su [questo blog](https://sfruttalagronoma.it/come-non-potare-il-capitozzo/)

Answer (score 2):

Sul [Grande dizionario della lingua italiana](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI02/GDLI_02_ocr_701.pdf&parola=capitozzo) (il cosiddetto *Battaglia*) si trova

> **Capitòzza**, sf.  (raro *capitozzo*,  sm.).  Agric. Albero   potato  di  tutti  i  rami,  in  modo  che 
>   rimangano le fronde soltanto in cima; chioma dell’albero così potato

Infatti, su questo dizionario appaiono alcuni esempi letterari di uso di "capitozza" e "capitozzo" tra i quali si trova precisamente la citazione di Pavese della domanda. In questo contesto, si tratterebbe dunque della chioma di un salice che era stato potato in modo che le fronde rimanessero soltanto in cima.

Comment: Ho appena saputo dell'esistenza di questo dizionario online grazie alla recente [entrata di @DaG su questo post del Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/123/707).